# Генеалогическое дерево. Вёрстка

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Требуется реализовать юзабельное генеалогическое дерево родители/дети (фамилия, имя, отчество) работающее в браузере ПК (мобильный размер опционален, но не обязателен). При клике на родителя должны разворачиваться дети. Вопрос скорее не как реализовать технически, а как сделать удобно и красиво. Приветствуются ссылки на примеры удачных решений.

Comment: Как пример: https://gojs.net/latest/samples/familyTree.html

Answer (score 1):

Есть такой пример генеалогического дерева https://github.com/luciepokorna/collapsible-family-tree
который использует [D3 (Data-Driven Documents or D3.js)](https://github.com/d3/d3/wiki). В этом примере как раз дочерние элементы отображаются по клику.
[image: генеалогическое дерево]

Еще в галерее примеров есть подобная реализация, но уже посвежее версия https://beta.observablehq.com/@mbostock/collapsible-tree
[image: collapsible-tree]